# Throws Exception Error in Java

Tags: java, file, exception

I'm working on a type of inventory program that deals with reading in a list of items from a file and I'm having some trouble.

Here's the code I have finished so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*; 

public class Store { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Book[] books = readInventory();

        for (Book book : books) {
            System.out.printf("ISBN: %s, Price: %f, Copies: %d%n",
            book.getISBN(), book.getPrice(), book.getCopies()); 
        }
    }

    public static Book[] readInventory() throws Exception {
        Book[] books = new Book[15];
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("../instr/prog4.dat");
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(file);
        String isbn;
        double price;
        int copies;
        int i = 0;

        while (fin.hasNext()) {
             isbn = fin.next();
                if (fin.hasNextDouble()); {
                    price = fin.nextDouble();
                }
                if (fin.hasNextInt()); {
                    copies = fin.nextInt();
                }
             Book book = new Book(isbn, price, copies);
             books[i] = book;
             i++;
        }
        fin.close();
        return books;
}

    public static void printInfo(Book[] books) {
        for(int x=0; x<books.length; x++) {
            System.out.println("ISBN: " + books[x].getISBN() + "\n Price: " +
            books[x].getPrice() + "\n Copies: " + books[x].getCopies());
        }   
    }
}

class Book {
    private String isbn;
    private double price;
    private int copies;

    public Book(String isbnNum, double priceOfBook, int copiesInStock) {
        isbn = isbnNum;
        price = priceOfBook;    
        copies = copiesInStock;
    }

    public String getISBN() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getCopies() {
        return copies;
    }

    public void setISBN(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setCopies(int copies) {
        this.copies = copies;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("ISBN: %s, Price: %f, Copies: %d%n",
             this.getISBN(), this.getPrice(), this.getCopies());
    }
}
```

The program compiles fine, but when I run the program I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:855)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1364)
    at Store.readInventory(Store.java:31)
    at Store.main(Store.java:13)
```

Here is the contents of the file I am supposed to use:

```
1234567 31.67 0
1234444 98.50 4
1235555 27.89 2
1235566 102.39 6
1240000 75.65 4
1247761 19.95 12
1248898 155.91 0
1356114 6.95 17
1698304 45.95 3
281982X 31.90 5
```

I have been looking at another program I wrote recently that dealt with reading files to see that I was throwing the exceptions in the same types of places and it appears that I am (everything dealing with the file in that program was in the main method so that was the only one throwing an exception). From what I remember from an earlier Java programming class, we were supposed to throw exceptions at the main method and any other methods that deal with the file, so in this case I have the one on main and another on my readInventory() method.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are checking `fin.hasNext()`, which tells you there is at least *one* thing left in the file, but then you assume there are 15 books in the file. Does your file really have all the data you are trying to read?

Comment: Well part of the directions was to create an array of type Book that would hold up to 15 book objects, but the file actually only contains 10 rows (each row consists of the ISBN, price, and amount in stock).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for next value before reading to avoid such exception as you are doing for `isbn` but not for `price` and `copies`.

sample code:

```
 if(fin.hasNextDouble()){
      price = fin.nextDouble();
 }
 if(fin.hashNextInt()){
     copies = fin.nextInt();
 }
```

For example [Scanner#nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method throws:

- `InputMismatchException` - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
- `NoSuchElementException` - if input is exhausted
- `IllegalStateException` - if this scanner is closed

---

You are creating array of size 15 where is there is only 10 line in file that result in `NullPointerException`. Use [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) in that case.

You can use [Java 7 - The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) for better resource management even in case of error.

sample code

```
public static BookDetail[] readInventory() throws Exception {
    List<BookDetail> books = new ArrayList<BookDetail>();
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("../instr/prog4.dat");
    try (Scanner fin = new Scanner(file)) {
        String isbn;
        double price = 0;
        int copies = 0;
        while (fin.hasNext()) {
            isbn = fin.next();
            if (fin.hasNextDouble()) {
                price = fin.nextDouble();
            }
            if (fin.hasNextInt()) {
                copies = fin.nextInt();
            }
            BookDetail book = new BookDetail(isbn, price, copies);
            books.add(book);
        }
    }
    return books.toArray(new BookDetail[books.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. Just trying to figure out where exactly this should go in my code and what all will need to be deleted to cut down on any redundancy?

Comment: Still working on trying to implement this code. One of the errors I'm getting is a "'try' without 'catch' or 'finally'" I'm trying to read and figure out where to put the catch or finally, but I keep getting the same errors.

Comment: I'm also getting several errors on my printInfor method "Store.java:72: illegal start of expression public void printInfo(Book[] books) {
^
Store.java:72: illegal start of expression
        public void printInfo(Book[] books) {
               ^
Store.java:72: ';' expected
        public void printInfo(Book[] books) {
                             ^
Store.java:72: ';' expected
        public void printInfo(Book[] books) {"

Comment: this is compiler error? Are you using any IDE? if not then use it.

Comment: Yes, these are compiler errors. I'm currently not since our professor has us working with the UNIX system, but I can try it. I'll just have to get the file moved over from the No Machine (remote UNIX login) to my PC

Comment: I have copied the file into Dr Java, but am still getting the same "'try' without 'catch' or 'finally'" error

Comment: just copy the code from my post. it is `try()` instead of `try{}`

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting 8 compiler errors, "8 errors found:
File: C:\Users\HiTechRedneck\Desktop\Summer II 2014\Store.java  [line: 47]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BookDetail
  location: class Store
File: C:\Users\HiTechRedneck\Desktop\Summer II 2014\Store.java  [line: 48]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class List
  location: class Store
File: C:\Users\HiTechRedneck\Desktop\Summer II 2014\Store.java  [line: 48]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BookDetail
  location: class Store

Comment: File: C:\Users\HiTechRedneck\Desktop\Summer II 2014\Store.java  [line: 48]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class Store
File: C:\Users\HiTechRedneck\Desktop\Summer II 2014\Store.java  [line: 48]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BookDetail
  location: class Store
File: C:\Users\HiTechRedneck\Desktop\Summer II 2014\Store.java  [line: 62]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BookDetail
  location: class Store

Comment: File: C:\Users\HiTechRedneck\Desktop\Summer II 2014\Store.java  [line: 62]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BookDetail
  location: class Store
File: C:\Users\HiTechRedneck\Desktop\Summer II 2014\Store.java  [line: 66]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BookDetail
  location: class Store

Comment: please take your time and try to find out the reason. there is no way to post the error in such a ways.

Comment: Sorry, this is just all really confusing

Comment: So all these variables like BookDetail[], List, etc, are they replacing variables I had already declared or are they just completely new? I'm just trying to wrap my head around this and figure out exactly what this portion of code is doing. I mean, I know what it's doing, but it's doing it using a bunch of things I've never had any experience with before, so it's really overwhelming.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are checking if the file has more data, then you attempt to read 15 books, no matter what. Your for-loop goes from 0 to books.length-1, whatever is in the file.

Since you don't know (in theory) how many books there are in the file, you need to check `fin.hasNext` before reading each book.

So get rid of your for-loop and replace your reading code with something like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (fin.hasNext()) {
     // read book here and assign to books[i]

     // increment i for next iteration
     i++;
}
```

The while condition `fin.hasNext()` will be checked before reading each book. When it returns false, you'll stop looping, and `i` will be the number of books you read.

Note that you're still assuming that each book has all its fields. If there was only half a book in the file, your code would still crash. But that's probably a good thing, since there's not really a way you can recover from that, and presumably you can assume you will receive only well-formed input.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use exception handling. I especially recommend using try with resources, since you forget to close the scanner that you are using.

You need to check in the code that you receive all the information that you need for each book. You don't want to have only partial information on the book just because you couldn't receive the rest of the data on that particular book.